# acts as commentable: comment body formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

I think I have a working version of acts_as_commenting_with_threading in my rails app, but it seems like the body of every comment is saved with weird formatting.  How do I remove the formatting in my view so it only displays the text (and not the formatting)?  For example, if I type the text "test comment," the body of the comment is saved as "---\nbody: test comment\n".  I tried html_safe, but it didn't work.

**step.rb**

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    acts_as_commentable
    friendly_id :position

    has_ancestry :orphan_strategy => :adopt

    attr_accessible :description, :name, :position, :project_id, :images_attributes, :parent_id, :ancestry, :published_on

    belongs_to :project
    has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => :true

    validates :name, :presence => true

end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @commentText = params[:comment]
    @user = current_user
    @comment = Comment.build_from(@project.steps.find(params[:step_id]), @user.id, @commentText)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html {redirect_to :back}
      else
        format.html { render :action => 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
 <div class="stepComments">
                <% if step.comment_threads.count >0 %>
                  <% step.comment_threads.each do |stepComment| %>
                    <% if stepComment.body.length>0 %>
                      <%= render :partial => 'comments', :locals => {:comment=> stepComment} %>
                    <% end %>
                    <br>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
```

**_comments.html.erb**

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="userIcon">
    <%= User.find(comment.user_id).username %>
    <%= image_tag(User.where(:id=>comment.user_id).first.avatar_url(:thumb), :class=>"commentAvatar img-polaroid")%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= comment.body %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This prints: "---\nbody: test comment\n"

Answer (score 0):

The rails helper [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) will print using the formatting rules so you will get just the text.

For example, `<% simple_format(comment.body) %>`

Comment: thanks for your help.  I tried this out, but it still leaves the formatting issues.

Comment: Have you tried [squishing](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish) the strings before saving?

Comment: I tried squishing, but it doesn't remove the strange "-- body" tag in the beginning of the body.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to do it besides just edited the string manually.  This is what I ended up using:

```
<%= comment.body.slice((comment.body.index(' ')+1..comment.body.length)) %>
```

It seems very odd that there isn't some built in function for doing this...

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a quite simple solution; I had been calling the parameter incorrectly.  It should have been:

```
@commentText = params[:comment][:body]
```